# Stuggling to access my localhost with xampp

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to access my localhost in order to reach phpmyadmin and change mysql password, however when I type "localhost" into the browser it says the page cannot be found. I have started Apache and MySQL in XAMPP - I initially had issues starting Apache but followed a tutorial which told be to change my Main Port to 8080 and my SSL port to 4433, which was all fine and dandy - that's running now - but could that have something to do with the localhost still not working?

Comment: You didn't provide any input on the answer I provided. Gently reminding you to give some feedback / vote / accept if that helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change your http port 80 and SSL to 443 in order to use the default `localhost` without `:8080` or `:4433`. In order to do that, you need to check that nothing is already running on these ports. That would typically be another web server.